# Javascript function only working on second click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am trying to hide/show elements in a navigational overlay on phones using Javascript. I have it working as it on the second click shows the element, and thereafter function each time i click. But it does not work on the first click and i cant seem to understand why.

Here is my code:

```js
function hidelinks() {

  if ( document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display =="none"){
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display ="block";
  } else {
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej2")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display ="none";
  }


}
```

```css
#secondmenu {
display: none;
}
```

```html
        <div  id="myTopnav" class="overlay" >
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            
            <div class="overlay-content ">
              <ul class="nobull">
                <li><a onclick="hidelinks()"  href="#">Om madskoler</a></li>
                  <ul id="secondmenu" class="nobull">
                      <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Madskoler kort fortalt</a></li>
                        <ul class="nobull">
                            <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Arrangører</a></li>
                            <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Samarbejde med ældresagen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Hvad er Madskoler?</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Etniske Madskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Ungdomsmadskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Praktiske oplysninger</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Maden på Madskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Salgs- og leveringsbetingelser</a></li>
                  </ul>
                <li><a  href="#">Tilmeld dit barn</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Bliv instruktør</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Sponsorer og ambassadører</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Nyheder</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="logout-button">Instruktør login</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I do not know where it goes wrong!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please add the `closeNav` function. Your snippet throws an error.

Comment: The `.style` object only shows styles that are directly coded on the HTML element. Styles from CSS are not included.

Comment: @JeremyHarris that's beside the point for the particular question. To see the problem without triggering errors just click "Om madskoler", then click it again. What happens the second time around should have happened on the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first run the style.display property is equal to an empty string. That's why it only work on the second click.

You can make a second comparation like this:

```
 if (document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display == "") {
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
```

Or invert the condition: `...display != "block"`

Or you can set the element [style inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) `<ul id="secondmenu" class="nobull" style="display: block">`

Or you can set it with javascript:

`document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display = "none"`

```js
function hidelinks() {

  if (document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display == "") {
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej2")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display = "none";
  }


}
```

```css
#secondmenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTopnav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <div class="overlay-content ">
    <ul class="nobull">
      <li><a onclick="hidelinks()" href="#">Om madskoler</a></li>
      <ul id="secondmenu" class="nobull">
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Madskoler kort fortalt</a></li>
        <ul class="nobull">
          <li><a id="thirdlink" href="#">Arrangører</a></li>
          <li><a id="thirdlink" href="#">Samarbejde med ældresagen</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Hvad er Madskoler?</a></li>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Etniske Madskoler</a></li>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Ungdomsmadskoler</a></li>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Praktiske oplysninger</a></li>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Maden på Madskoler</a></li>
        <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Salgs- og leveringsbetingelser</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Tilmeld dit barn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bliv instruktør</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sponsorer og ambassadører</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nyheder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="logout-button">Instruktør login</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display` return empty string ... so just change the 'if' and it work ...

```js
function hidelinks() {

  if ( document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display != "block"){
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display ="block";
  } else {
    console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
    console.log("hej2")
    document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display = "none";
  }


}
```

```css
#secondmenu {
display: none;
}
```

```html
        <div  id="myTopnav" class="overlay" >
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            
            <div class="overlay-content ">
              <ul class="nobull">
                <li><a onclick="hidelinks()"  href="#">Om madskoler</a></li>
                  <ul id="secondmenu" class="nobull">
                      <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Madskoler kort fortalt</a></li>
                        <ul class="nobull">
                            <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Arrangører</a></li>
                            <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Samarbejde med ældresagen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Hvad er Madskoler?</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Etniske Madskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Ungdomsmadskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Praktiske oplysninger</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Maden på Madskoler</a></li>
                        <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Salgs- og leveringsbetingelser</a></li>
                  </ul>
                <li><a  href="#">Tilmeld dit barn</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Bliv instruktør</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Sponsorer og ambassadører</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Nyheder</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="logout-button">Instruktør login</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you change styles with javascript it becomes an **inline styling**. **Therefore you need to put your display: none styling inline or set it with javascript from the beginning.** (Code below)

2) Another solution is to change the if condition to:

`if ( document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display != "block"){ }`

```js
function hidelinks() {

 if ( document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display === "none"){
   console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
   console.log("hej")
   document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display = "block";
 } else {
   console.log(document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display)
   console.log("hej2")
   document.getElementById("secondmenu").style.display ="none";
 }
  
  
  }
```

```html
    <div  id="myTopnav" class="overlay" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        
        <div class="overlay-content ">
          <ul class="nobull">
            <li><a onclick="hidelinks()"  href="#">Om madskoler</a></li>
              <ul id="secondmenu" class="nobull" style="display: none">
                  <li><a id="secondlink" href="#">Madskoler kort fortalt</a></li>
                    <ul class="nobull">
                        <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Arrangører</a></li>
                        <li><a id="thirdlink"  href="#">Samarbejde med ældresagen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Hvad er Madskoler?</a></li>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Etniske Madskoler</a></li>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Ungdomsmadskoler</a></li>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Praktiske oplysninger</a></li>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Maden på Madskoler</a></li>
                    <li><a id="secondlink"  href="#">Salgs- og leveringsbetingelser</a></li>
              </ul>
            <li><a  href="#">Tilmeld dit barn</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Bliv instruktør</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Sponsorer og ambassadører</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Nyheder</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="logout-button">Instruktør login</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a great idea to put styling into the HTML

Comment: @MikeBrockington True - but it does not make a difference as the styling gets set inline through javascript anyways, right?

Comment: Until someone else comes along and updates it in some way, or even worse, when the original author forgets why it was like that, and tidies it up.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the comment :)